# Is it possible to count font size from total text height?

Tags: php, font-size, imagick

I play with PHP `ImagickDraw()` object and my purpose is to calculate font size that i need to set to fill a container with specific height.

[image: Font height 550px]

In example above i used Arial font and just set the font size as 601px manually which gave me the height 550px. Ultimately i want to use more fonts. I need to type a one-line text. Just one or two words.

I know there is `Imagick::queryFontMetrics()` which give me some font properties, but no idea is there any way to get exact font size.

Comment: What version Imagick are you using and what font are you looking to find out the precise height of?

Comment: Imagick version is 7.0.7-11. Well, there is above 50 different fonts i want to use, like **Kalam Bold**, **Berkshire Swash Regular**, **Montserrat Alternates Extra Bold Italic** and many more. As I guess that each font has different metrics which makes it more difficult to resolve it.